# How to Resize UI elements for iPhones?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, iphone

I am designing UI for an application which is going to be available for both Android and iPhone. While for android, slicing/chopping up the UI elements is pretty much simple and straight forward, we have to resize the UI elements for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi.
i.e., 36X36, 42X42, 72X72 and 96X96 respectively. However, am not sure about resizing the UI elements for iPhone. I read somewhere that we have to resize the UI elements in @x and @2x sizes and also I've read we need to change the ppi of the UI elements as well, like 163ppi and 326ppi.

So, I am confused between:
1) By resizing image.png @x and @2x 
2) By changing the image.png's 163ppi and 326ppi versions.

Which one is the appropriate way?

Comment: Related question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19451/defining-resolution-or-layout-size-for-iphone-ipad-devices?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think resize of the png's is the best method,

for Retina ex:-sample@2x.png

for standard 50% of retina ex:-sample.png..

Comment: So is it like, If I have an image of a resolution, say, 200X300, so will I have to make an image of 400X600? without changing the ppi?

Comment: actually ppi is used for only taking print, for using in device no need to bother about ppi...we have to be care in resolution only